# Should the overuse of colored text be discouraged?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I have just edited [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2402349/ambiguity-in-the-definition-of-locally-finiteness-of-a-collection-of-subsets-of), because apart from some spelling mistakes the asker had colored a good portion of the text (not the equations!), almost as if they wanted to convey what they felt were the important bits, or even the intonation of the text (why in the world would one highlight a "but"?).

As some had pointed out in the comments there, this practice made the question (a valid question, otherwise) very difficult to read and understand. Now the asker is requesting that I revert the question to its older likes, but I couldn't find relevant meta post to link to them.

Should this use of color be discouraged?

Comment: When I first read this question, my reaction was skeptical - I can see how overuse of colors can be annoying, and why an eager newbie to MathJax might be trigger-happy with his/her newly-learned trick, but colors can often provide clarity for people that have a hard time following the steps and logical implications of an algebraic proof.

And then I looked at the post you linked to. Now I realize how absolutely nauseating such an abuse of colors can be. You will be happy to know that I agree with you entirely. :P

Comment: [A related thread.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4195) [And another one.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23150)

Comment: With enough text in the MathJax, you can make my page render slower, or not at all :( Its like those posts where the answers are filled with lots of MathJax or there are a lot of answers (popular question) and it takes forever for the page to fully render, except here, the problem is avoidable.

Comment: By definition of the word "overuse", the question in the title can only be answered in the affirmative. The real question is, how much use is overuse?

Comment: @Gerry, in Tommy, "I had no reason to be overoptimistic"  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoW_0NuaPj4

Comment: As explained [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/would-html-unicode-formatting-cause-troubles/17543#17543), MathJax might be useful for people using screen readers. Does anybody know some details to which extent are MathJax colors "screen readers friendly"?

Comment: @MartinSleziak from a comment to the answer you linked to (my emphasis): "MathJax should be used *only for mathematical content*, **not for** adding white space, or italics, or **colored text,** or background colors, or line breaks in comments, or other display hacks, to textual (non-math) content" I am not sure what your intent was, but if anything I'd say the linked to answer shows why this should not be done.

Comment: @Simply It is highly unlikely that coloring text will yield any significant performance impact on MathJax rendering since processing such is not at all computationally intensive.

Comment: @quid And Cantor wrote that infinitesimals should never be used. I value  both *opinions* similarly. One should use whatever tools are available to improve mathematical presentations.

Comment: @BillDubuque I would agree, lest someone decides to slaughter my page with it.

Comment: BTW perhaps you could add to your post also a [link to the original revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2402349/1) of that post. (For comparison.)

Comment: @quid Yes, it is mentioned there - but only briefly in a comment. I would still prefer to see either here on in some other related discussion on meta something a bit more detailed. (Somebody who actually uses screenreaders would probably be able to say whether things similar to above example are only minor inconvenience or whether this would really make the page virtually unreadable for them.)

Comment: To add to the previous comment, I certainly agree that MathJax is for mathematics and not for formatting and often edit posts in this way. (Although I remember your warning [from another meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/2314/using-mathjax-for-formating-bold-italics/2315#2315) do not like such edits to their posts.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak yes, this would be interesting. I think I misunderstood your initial comment a bit. On other sites there are sometimes discussions on using code-markup for emphasis like `this`. In such a discussion I read somebody saying that (certain) screen-readers will start to spell-out the marked up portion *letter-by-letter*. Of course this is not the same situation, but it to me it suggests that it possibly might be *extremely* annoying for some.

Comment: [“When I see equations, I see the letters in colors – I don't know why. As I'm talking, I see vague pictures of Bessel functions from Jahnke and Emde's book, with light-tan j's, slightly violet-bluish n's, and dark brown x's flying around. And I wonder what the hell it must look like to the students”](http://sdl.granthazard.com/exhibits/show/famous-synesthetes/famous-synesthetes-closer-look/richard-feynman) - Feynman.

Comment: ^ This. That's something that happens to me too. Only a few years ago I realized, to my great surprise, that not everybody does it (nobody in my family *didn't* do it, so conversations about "what color is this letter or number to you" were perfectly normal). And that's part of the reason why the question I linked bothered me so much: it got the colors in my head all mixed up

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Colored text *can* be useful. I can only think of one example at the moment, which is for highlighting correspondences between different parts of a piece of text, like so: $\frac{d}{dx} (\color{green}{x^3} + \color{blue}{x^2}) = \color{green}{3x^2} + \color{blue}{2x}$

Colored text is **not** useful for merely emphasizing or highlighting a bit of text; italics or bold should be used for this instead.

When colors are used merely for emphasis, or in a way which does not convey any meaningful information, then they are merely a distraction and should not be used.

So let's look at a brief quote from the original post:

> The above
> $\color{Red}{\text{fake}}$-$\color{Teal}{\text{definition}}$
> look likes much more simpler to understanding; at least for me.

> - If my proof is $\color{Green}{\text{true}}$;
>   then why $\color{Blue}{\text{John M. Lee}}$
>   did not use this $\color{Teal}{\text{definition}}$?

The colors here don't convey any information, so removing them was the right call, and they should not be re-added.

Comment: +1 the fact that colors within equations can be useful. Though I tend to not use it, I have found reading answers with large algebraic components that color is a very easy to understand way to group symbols in an algebraic manipulation in transitions from line to line, as you've demonstrated.

Comment: @Dominique That's a good idea. Done.

Answer (score 39):

> Please note the sarcasm.

---

I don't see any $\color{purple}{\text{problem}}$ with this, adding $\color{red}{\text{c}}\color{orange}{\text{o}}\color{green}{\text{l}}\color{blue}{\text{o}}\color{purple}{\text{r}}$ to text shouldn't reduce $\color{#12dd13}{\text{readibility}}$, nor should any other $\LaTeX$, such as $\boxed{\text{boxes}}$ $\require{cancel}\cancel{\text{or cancels}}$, even though markdown already provides most of anything you need <s>such as strikeouts</s>. Especially if I insist on using $\color{#5555dd}{\text{different colors for each set of words}}$ and some of the colors are simply so $\color{yellow}{bright}$ that I cannot read them. I would also assume that the it doesn't bother anyone if I omit the `\text` so that my words display $like~so$, or $\mathbb{LIKE~SO}$ when we can use asterisks to write *like so* and **LIKE SO**.

---

By the way, please DO NOT use yellow. It's literally impossible to read on a white background.

Comment: Is the misuse of a blockquote for emphasis part of the sarcasm? ;-) Anyhow I like the answer.

Comment: @quid No, not really, I sort of wanted to make that part stand out, and I wasn't feeling the whole "Large and bold" format.

Comment: The point was so that you didn't like it! $\ddot\frown$ mission failure I suppose.

Comment: Well, I do not like it in a literal sense, but as a good bad example.

Comment: This is Simply Beautiful Art :D

Comment: This feels like a high school text book.

Comment: @A---B Why omit the OP's intent?

Comment: @Did I thought that sarcasm was obvious without mentioning it.

Comment: @A---B But it ain't your post, ain't it? Except to correct obvious defects, one is not supposed to modify a post on a whim, especially if the edit twists the OP's intentions.

Comment: @A---B keeping it does no harm, removing it might confuse someone.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I believe you meant " It's literally impossible to read on a **white** background."

Comment: Yes, my bad @snb

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you for using $\ddot\frown$, happy to have learned that

Comment: I like how one of the colours is called 'greed'.

Comment: @JohnGowers xD How'd you notice?

Answer (score 35):

Yes. Yes.

A thousand times yes.

Markdown provides enough methods to draw attention to different parts of text, though **bold** and *italic* and even ***bold italic***, not to forget

> block quotes

when one wishes to quote a large section of text, to make using colors via MathJax completely unnecessary. Not only that, but a post written in a rainbow of colours is overly distracting and more often than not more difficult to read.

There is no reason to **abuse** MathJax to format text on this site. Lots of Stack Exchange sites get by without it (by virtue of not having MathJax enabled). So can we.

Comment: Is there a place here in meta where all these formatting suggestions are collected, that I could reference if this happens again? If so, has this issue already been included there?

Comment: @giobrach I cannot think of an reference of that sort. The various ways that a user could "enhance" their posts through idiosyncratic formatting choices is pretty extensive. I think the guiding principle is that posts are not meant for any one person (even the asker of a question), and so posts should be in a form that benefits the largest number of users/potential passers-by.

Comment: @giobrach you could link to https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting that explains a bit about Markdown formatting. I believe some users are just unaware of this options, which can result in them using  `$\textbf{Theorem}$` instead on `**Theorem**` and alike. (Not really the current case, but it does happen.)

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you all.

Comment: -1 What a painfully constrained viewpoint. I encourage everyone to use every tool available to improve your mathematical expositions here.  I often use color in MathJax, e.g. to help readers follow logical flow, e.g. when identities or laws are applied, when substitutions are made, etc. Many readers have left positive remarks about how such annotations help them to better comprehend intricate arguments.

Comment: This issue goes far beyond and has nothing to do with sparse and intelligent use of color in equations. Take a look at the question I linked above – or at the sarcastic answer below

Comment: @giobrach Of course I have seen the extreme use of color in the question. My comment refers to the remarks in this *answer*, which are *not* constrained to the extreme cases in said question, but appear to be far more global claims (this was explained in a prior discussion here that was purged by moderators).

Answer (score 3):

preamble:

I strongly second Tanner Swett's answer that *judiciously* using coloured text to highlight correspondences is advantageous, while using coloured text for emphasis is tacky.

---

An oft-repeated suggestion is that, taking cognizance of colour blindness, colour use should be avoided when creating posts. I wonder how much this wisdom bears scrutiny: I'm not knowledgeable about colour blindness, but it has always seemed to me that such advice may be premised on the false assumption that colour-blind folks aren't able to discern colours.

[A quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=colour+combinations+colorblind+folks) reveals that there *are* colour palettes that are colourblind-friendly (perhaps related to colour contrasts). Apparently, one acceptable colour combination is $\color\red{\text{red}}$ & $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}.$

Could users who are knowledgeable about this topic please expand this post to add insights and and practicable suggestions. Thanks!

---

**A recent comment from the main site:**

- As a little disability hot-tip, red/green is a bad color combination for colorblindness. $\color{blue}{\text{Blue}}$ and $\color\orange{\text{orange}}\quad$ (or $\color\purple{\text{purple}}$ and $\color\orange{\text{orange)}}$ is one of the best combinations to guarantee that everyone reading your question can see the colors, which is really important if the colors are relevant!

  [- comment by HallaSurvivor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704298/why-all-models-of-computation-are-colorless#comment9958125_4704298)

Comment: I think this wisdom *does* bear scrutiny - the point is that you need to be careful when using colours, rather than not use them at all. However, lots of my family are colour blind, and from talking to them I've realised it is easier to just not use colours - colour blindness isn't a uniform thing, but sometimes one person can discern something while another cannot, even if both are for example red/green colour blind.

Comment: Also, [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.1618.pdf) is an interesting Nature opinion article on the topic :-)